# R code to produce a percent of column within a Shiny reactive framework

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, filtering, tidyverse

I'm developing an interactive flexdashboard Shiny app that subsets a dataframe, counts the accounts and produces a percent of that column. Then it pulls the percent value to place it into a `valueBox`.

The problem is when the data is subset and a column has 0%, `count()` and `tally()` remove it from the data.frame, and thus I can't place the 0% in the `valueBox`.

Here is a simplified example of the data:

```
key <- 1:9
county <- rep(c("a","b","c"), times = 3)
immigrant <- c(1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1)
df <- data.frame(key, county, immigrant)
df
  key county immigrant
1   1      a         1
2   2      b         0
3   3      c         1
4   4      a         0
5   5      b         0
6   6      c         1
7   7      a         1
8   8      b         0
9   9      c         1
```

The simplified Shiny app structure:

```
selectInput(inputId = "countyInput", label = "Select a county",
            choices = unique(df$county),
            selected = "a")

vboxfilter <- reactive({
  df %>% filter(county == req(input$countyInput)) %>% 
         filter(county == req(input$countyInput))
})

output$vimmigrant<- renderValueBox({

  v1 <- df() %>% 
          count(immigrant) %>% 
          mutate(Percent = paste0(round(n/sum(n)*100,2), "%"))

  x <- v1[[2,3]]

  valueBox(x)

})

valueBoxOutput("vimmigrant")
```

I generate the percent for the `valueBox` with

```
df %>% group_by(county) %>% count(immigrant) %>% mutate(perc = n/sum(n))

  county immigrant     n  perc
  <fct>      <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1 a              0     1 0.333
2 a              1     2 0.667
3 b              0     3 1    
4 c              1     3 1
```

Thus when the reactive function filters `county == "b"` it's unable to pull the value at `v1[[2,3]]` and generates an error. The `county` column is removed when is subsets the data.

I've searched quite a bit and can't find a solution to this. I'm new to Shiny and largely utilize `tidyverse` notation. I haven't been able to get reactive functions to work with bracketed notation, which I think is holding me back in this case.

I've looked into table() and other summary tools to simply extract the values as percents as different indexes, but no such luck.

Ideally, I'm looking for a workaround or a way to augment the `count()` function to produce

```
immigrant n  perc
  <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1   0     1 1.00%
2   1     2 0.00%
```

so I can use `v1[[2,3]]` to pull the value for the `valueBox`. Any workarounds or advice is warmly welcome.

Thanks for the help guys -- I hope the description of my problem was comprehensible.

Answer (score 0):

I am slightly confused on the issue but if you just want to pull whatever percentages are left after filter you could do

```
(df %>% group_by(county) %>% count(immigrant) %>% mutate(perc = immigrant/sum(n)))[,4]
```

I also think you are trying to get what percentage are immigrants so I changed the calculation to percent to `perc = immigrant/sum(n)` rather than `perc = n/sum(n)` but maybe I'm just not understanding your purpose fully.